# Splunk: find a portion of a value in a list

Tags: splunk

I have two CSV files:

- in the first file, there is a list of machines hostnames (ex: ABCZER12).
- and in the second file, I have a list of the first letters of the machines hostnames (ex: ABC), and each expression correspond to a location (ex: Europe, Brazil...).

An example of the first file:

- ABCZER12
- ABCSDF56
- ABCFHG76
- OPQYGT65
- XYTGHY41
- XYZRFV78

And an example of the second file:

- ABC => Europe
- OPQR => Brazil
- XY => USA

I need to associate each hostname with its corresponding location. To do that, I need to search for each hostname if its begining match with one of the expressions in the second list. Example: ABCZER12, ABCSDF56 and ABCFHG76 will match with ABC, means that those hostnames correspond to the location Europe.

Some hostnames can not match any of the expressions in the second list (ex: OPQYGT65).

In the second file, expressions does not always have the same amount of letters.

In the two files, there is no column that are the same, so I think that I can't use lookups to resolve my problem here.

If anyone have an idea to resolve my problem, it would be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :

- first file is source.csv,
- headline of sources.csv  is "host"
- second file is places.csv
- headlines of places.csv is "prefix" and "country"
- new desired field is Country

query:

```
|inputlookup source.csv |table host

|eval 
[|inputlookup places.csv |table prefix Country 
|eval search="like(host, \""+prefix+"%\"),\""+Country+"\"," 
|stats values(search) as search |nomv search 
|eval search=substr(search,1,length(search)-1) 
|eval search="Country=case("+search+")" |table search]
```

Explanation:
Splunk will run subsearch in the places.csv and convert the table to one eval string:

```
Country=case(like(a, "ABC%"),"Europe", like(a, "OPQR%"),"Brazil", like(a, "XY%"),"USA")
```

Then we are using "|eval" before the subsearch to use that eval.

The results acts like a lookup operation but with prefix rather then exact word detection.